# What is a Jaffe-Rechtin PLL?

Tags: noise, pll, control-loop, tracking

[Eberhardt Rechtin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberhardt_Rechtin) and Richard Jaffe (both involved in NASAs DSN) published [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3488909_Design_and_performance_of_phase-lock_circuits_capable_of_near-optimum_performance_over_a_wide_range_of_input_signal_and_noise_levels) (paywalled) on PLL-design and -performance back in 1955. It is referenced quite often, so I wanted to understand what makes a "Jaffe-Rechtin"-loop or -filter. I would have expected a wiki-article on a seemingly important concept after such a long time, but found ... nothing. Same for StackExchange.

From the abstract, I have the impression that a bandpass limiter in the loop is the distinctive element. Later JPL publications (this [technical report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19660008034.pdf) f.e.) do mention bandpass limiting, but the term Jaffe-Rechtin-filter was apparently not formed in 1966.

On the other hand, I found some remarks in the [IS-GPS redaction process](http://www.gps.gov/technical/icwg/meetings/2012/09/05/Comment_Resolution_Matrix_SiS_Docs_Sep12_Public_ICWG.pdf) (slide 2), that suggest that Jaffe-Rechtin-PLL is a vague term and needs clarification.

**What do engineers mean when they speak about a Jaffe-Rechtin-PLL?** What makes it special? Pointers to free publications are welcome if it would be lengthy to explain here.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of maths involved in the [paper](http://sci-hub.cc/10.1109/TIT.1955.1055125).

What I read of it they contend, with mathematical proofs, that a servo controlled variable filter (bandpass limiter) that matches the error signal bandwidth (rather than the input signal) will be better (they go so far as to say approximately optimal) than simple bandpass filtering.

Comment: Good to have the original paper. I will see what I can figure out from it.